# converting request.getparameter() result to date

Tags: jsp, date, request, simpledateformat

I have a jsp page which takes an input type date. In the servlet am using request.getParameter() and SimpleDateFormat to get the date which the user has input.

My problem is i only want to get the day, month and year but i also get the time, meaning when i display back the date i display in this format- Day Name : Month: Day of Month : Time : Year, but i only want to display - Year : Month : Day of Month.

Here is what i have done :

```
Date startDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("startDate")); //get the parameter convert it to a data type Date.

out.println(startDate); //Display the date
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is you are passing Date (java.util.Date) object to println method. println internally calls [Date#toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) on the date object, which results in the format that you don't want.

#### Solution

If your problem is within servlet you want Date object then

```
String startDateStr = request.getParameter("startDate");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
//surround below line with try catch block as below code throws checked exception
Date startDate = sdf.parse(startDateStr);
//do further processing with Date object
......
....
```

If you want to print the date then you can convert the *date to String*  according to your format and pass that string to println method

```
out.println(sdf.format(startDate)); //this is what you want yyyy-MM-dd
```

#### See also

- [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- [Date tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
// expected input format in YYYY-MM-DD???
SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String parameter = request.getParameter("startDate");
Date date = in.parse(parameter);

// output format
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
out.println(fmt.format(date));
```

But if the input format and the output format are the same, then why not simply `out.println(parameter)`? Or do you want to validate the input in addition, for example by calling setLenient(false) on the input format?

Comment: Keep in mind that out.println(startDate) implicitly use the toString()-method of java.util.Date!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the opposite of `SimpleDateFormat.parse`, say `SimpleDateFormat.format`. But, sincerely, I don't understand why you want to parse and format back with the same pattern... `X = format(parse(X))`

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to convert util.Date to sql.Date, you can call getTime method after parsing your string and then create a sql.Date object..**

String birth = request.getParameter("birthdate");

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

long l = sdf.parse(birth).getTime();
Date date = new Date(l);